# SyntaxError: (unicode error) while using pd.read_table for a txt file

Tags: python, pandas, unicode

I am reading a txt file with a pattern into Pandas:

```
Alabama[edit]
Auburn (Auburn University)[1]
Florence (University of North Alabama)
Jacksonville (Jacksonville State University)[2]
Livingston (University of West Alabama)[2]
Montevallo (University of Montevallo)[2]
Troy (Troy University)[2]
Tuscaloosa (University of Alabama, Stillman College, Shelton State)[3][4]
Tuskegee (Tuskegee University)[5]
Alaska[edit]
Fairbanks (University of Alaska Fairbanks)[2]
Arizona[edit]
Flagstaff (Northern Arizona University)[6]
Tempe (Arizona State University)
Tucson (University of Arizona)
```

by:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table('file path', sep='\n', header=None)
```

But I am getting this error:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in ` 
enter code here`position 65-66: truncated \uXXXX escape
```

I do not really understand why. I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: Is that the *exact* content of a sample file that will reproduce the error?  I don't see a "truncated \uXXXX escape" in that sample.  Please provide a sample and code that reproduces the error message.  See the [mcve] guidelines.

Comment: The txt file comes from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_college_towns#College_towns_in_the_United_States

Comment: So it is not a [mcve]. Please read the guidelines.

Comment: The data is a saved text file from the wiki page above:

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to set correct encoding to load the file.

Try

```
df = pd.read_table('file path', sep='\n', header=None, encoding='utf-8')
```

or

```
df = pd.read_table('file path', sep='\n', header=None, encoding='WINDOWS-1252')
```

If it still doesn't work, you can use a package like [chardet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) to detect the encoding of the file and then load it.

Comment: Well, I just wanted to let you know once I entered the file path with "/" instead of "\" everything worked. Thank you